# Vulkan - how to show that executing two commands without sync creates corrupt data?

Tags: synchronization, vulkan

I wrote a simple test tends to create a sync issue by executing two copy commands in parallel, so I can have a way to add then sync techniques, to be familiar and experienced with.
Unfortunately, it seems that there is an implicit sync , because everything works fine without any sync mechanism I do.

The test does the follow:

1. (sync) Update buffer A with data by CPU.
2. (async) Copy Buffer A to B
3. (async) Copy Buffer B to C
4. Wait for device idle
5. (sync) read buffer C data by CPU

Steps (2) and (3) are done without sync, so I would except that transferring data from B to C will happen while data is still written from A to B, and in this way to have corrupted data in C. But reading C to CPU shows always correct results, it always equal to data written to A.

Changing buffers size to 1G doesn't help, it still has perfect results (which is not perfect in this case :) )

Hardware: Quadro RTX 5000 with Max-Q Design apiVersion: 4202651 driver: 1938276352

```
        // Given:      
        // VkCommandPool cp;
        // VkDevice device;
        // VkQueue queue;
        // VkBuffer bufferA; 1G stage buffer (updated by cpu, has gpu src transfer usage)
        // VkBuffer bufferB; 1G buffer (has gpu src and gpu dst transfer usage)
        // VkBuffer bufferC; 1G stage buffer (read by cpu, has gpu dst transfer usage)

        // create command buffer
        VkCommandBufferAllocateInfo cbai = {};
        cbai.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_ALLOCATE_INFO;
        cbai.pNext = 0;
        cbai.commandBufferCount = 1;
        cbai.level = VkCommandBufferLevel::VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY;
        cbai.commandPool = cp;
        std::vector<VkCommandBuffer> cbs(1);
        vkAllocateCommandBuffers(device, &cbai, cbs.data());

        // set copy info
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo cbbi = {};
        cbbi.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
        cbbi.pNext = 0;
        cbbi.pInheritanceInfo = 0;

        VkBufferCopy copyRegion = {};
        copyRegion.srcOffset = 0;
        copyRegion.dstOffset = 0;
        copyRegion.size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;

        // record copy commands 
        vkBeginCommandBuffer(cbs[0], &cbbi);
        vkCmdCopyBuffer(cbs[0], bufferA, bufferB, 1, &copyRegion);
        vkCmdCopyBuffer(cbs[0], bufferB, bufferC, 1, &copyRegion);
        vkEndCommandBuffer(cbs[0]);

        // execution of command buffer
        VkSubmitInfo si = {};
        si.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
        si.commandBufferCount = 1;
        si.pCommandBuffers = cbs.data();
        vkQueueSubmit(queue, 1, &si, VK_NULL_HANDLE);

        // wait execution finished
        vkDeviceWaitIdle(device);

        // free command buffers
        vkFreeCommandBuffers(device, cp, 1, cbs.data());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Undefined behavior is undefined. You cannot write any UB code which is guaranteed across implementations to have *any* particular behavior. Including specifically wrong behavior.

Maybe there is an implicit synchronization. Or maybe the GPU only can execute one transfer operation at a time on that queue. Or something else. The point is that the code has UB, but you can't make that UB manifest in a certain way.